# how to pass string comand to shell pipe to execute it (output of awk)

Tags: command-line, awk

For example this works:

```
echo 1 // output: 1
```

This doesn't work:

```
'echo 1' | "/bin/sh" // output: echo 1: command not found
```

Why string because i have output of awk and i need to pass the string to execute some command like this:

```
awk '{ print 'chmod 755 "$0"' | "/bin/sh"}' file.txt
```

I need to use string like that because i guess it let me put the parameter where i want in the command.

So i first wanted try it execute manually from bash to see if it works before i put it in the awk print command.

Comment: Try: `echo 'echo 1' | "/bin/sh"`

Comment: ha that works good. now to make the awk pipe working though

Comment: haha shell is so powerfull.. i can read top ips from apache access log and get the user agent for each the ip using the following (brute) command: cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20 | awk '{print "grep -F "$2" /var/log/apache2/access.log | tail -1" | "/bin/sh"}' | awk -v FPAT='([^ ]*)|("[^"]*")' '{print $10}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* passing a string to the shell - however the string you are passing is `1`

To pass `echo 1` you need something like

```
echo 'echo 1' | /bin/sh
```

or

```
printf '%s' 'echo 1' | /bin/sh
```

(outside of `awk`, you don't need to quote `/bin/sh`).